# Can't retrieve RTCVideoSourceStats from PeerConnection in firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I am trying to get the height and width of a localStream that I'm sending over a peerconnection from the [media-source stats](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcvideosourcestats) retrieved from the [PeerConnection.getStats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getStats) or RTCRtpSender.getStats, but it does not get returned in the stats report. Does firefox not support these stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented yet. To see a full dump of stats check [this sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/)

While not very up-to-date https://webrtc-stats.callstats.io/verify give a high-level overview of what statistics are implemented by different browsers.